# Create public variable Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

Hello that's my nodejs **commandline** to get the weather on current position.

```
// Index.js
// Modules
const program = require('commander');
const clear = require('clear');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const request = require('ajax-request');
const fs = require('fs');
const json = require('read-data').json;
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile')

// Http Request to freegeoi.net
request({
  url: "http://freegeoip.net/json/",
  method: "GET",
  data: {
     format: "json"
  },
}, function(err, res, body) {

  // Parse the result
  const data = JSON.parse(body);

  // Extracting coordinates from data
  let lat = data.latitude;
  let long = data.longitude;
});

// forecase key
const key = "***********************";
// full forecast api url
const url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${key}/${lat},${long}`;
```

The problem is this: i want to get variable **lat** and **long** out of the *request* function.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change `let lat = ...` to `var lat = ...` because `let` scopes to the nearest `{}` block where as `var` scopes globally -- but this is generally bad practice.

A better option would be to call another function at the end of the request callback:

```
function processLatLong(lat, long) {
    //do something with lat long
}

request({
  url: "http://freegeoip.net/json/",
  method: "GET",
  data: {
     format: "json"
  },
}, function(err, res, body) {

  // Parse the result
  const data = JSON.parse(body);

  // Extracting coordinates from data
  let lat = data.latitude;
  let long = data.longitude;
  processLatLong(lat, long);
});
```